# Katharine Hepburn, polyglot?

Tags: casting, katharine-hepburn

In *Woman of the Year* (1942), Katharine Hepburn speaks English, French, Russian, German, Spanish and Greek.  Presumably she had good coaching; but, given her background, I would be surprised to learn that she did not speak three languages for real.

So: what is known about her linguistic repertoire?

I conjecture that it included Italian, because her Spanish had what sounded to me like an Italian accent; that is, had I not listened closely, nor had notice to expect Spanish, the rhythm would suggest Italian to my ear.

Comment: Her wiki page says she spoke French quite fluently but no more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### English (mother tongue), French (sub-fluency), Italian (limited proficiency).

Her various biographies indicate that she spoke fluent French, after having spent some time in Paris. They make no mention of any other languages spoken with any particular proficiency.

> Fundless, Kit haunted libraries and museums during the day and spent
> most of her evenings under the watchful, somewhat paternal eye of the
> bistro patron. Her French grew fluent and her naïveté worked to
> protect her.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Katharine Hepburn: A Remarkable Woman*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/52355980-katharine-hepburn) - Anne Edwards</sup></sub>

Despite having spent some years living with a French-speaker she notably had problems communicating with Coco Chanel in her later years and had to resort to English.

> Kate had trouble communicating with Chanel because her French was
> poor, but she left her a souvenir from The African Queen - an African
> brass medallion - along with a note.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Katharine Hepburn*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30840531-katharine-hepburn) by Grace Carter</sup></sub>

Her Italian was tourist-level and appears to have been gained from spending time with her family's cook, Fanny Ciarrier who was of French-Italian heritage.

> There was indeed six inches of snow on the ground and still snowing.
> It was about twelve-thirty or one o’clock. My Italian, such as it was,
> took us to the Avis rental desk, very handy in the Milano airport.
>
> <sub><sup>[*Me: Stories of my Life*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/145397) by Katharine Hepburn</sup></sub>

There's no good indication that she spoke six languages.